# Array omitting lines in one part of code, but showing it in another

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm creating an String[] and in this section of code I miss the lines of code I'm checking for!
*Please note: I do know this is not the best approach for checking, but this is just a "proof of concept" and will be changed later on. Anyway, here is the code that gives me the problem:

```
private void checkMethods() {

    for (int i  = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String s  = array[i];
        System.out.println(s);

        if(array[i].contains("onEnable()")) {
            System.out.println("enable");
            array[i] = MethodUpdate.onEnable;
        } 

        else if (isOnDisable(s)) {
            System.out.println("disable");
            array[i] = MethodUpdate.onDisable;
        } 

        else if (isOverride(s)) {
            if (checkNextLine(array[i++])) {
                array[i] = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this returns the following:

```
public class DummyBukkitClass extends JavaPlugin {

  @Override
    // Some Profound code can be found here
  }

  @Override
    // The Profound code is now ending =(
  }

}
```

However in the following code it returns what I need it too:

```
   public void updateFile(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    pw = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("classes/DummyBukkitClass.java"));
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        pw = new PrintWriter(file);

        String line;
        int index = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            array[index] = line;
            index++;
        }


    } finally {
        checkMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            pw.println(array[i]);
        }

        br.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Now this returns:

```
public class DummyBukkitClass extends JavaPlugin {

  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    // Some Profound code can be found here
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable() {
    // The Profound code is now ending =(
  }

}
```

I'm just stumped as to why the 1st one is omitting 2 lines, while i call it right after they are there! They are able to be printed all throughout the adding process; and I can print them before the checkMethods() is called. Please help!

Thanks you!

EDIT:

To fix the problem I needed to change:

```
        else if (isOverride(array[i])) {
            if (checkNextLine(array[i++])) {
                array[i] = "";
            }
        }
```

In checkMethods() to:

```
        else if (isOverride(array[i])) {
            if (checkNextLine(array[i+1])) { //HERE
                array[i] = "";
            }
        }
```

The reason behind that is this: I was increasing the size of 'i' then using that 'i' again without resetting it. 'i+1' fixes that because you are not setting a new value to i.

Comment: you want to do `br.flush()` before closing it? Also, your code is slightly incomplete for us to understand what happened before finally block (i.e. try/catch bits).

Comment: @hagubear EDIT: Nope, you can't flush it :P

Comment: @user1768369     still need more of your try/catch code...only having finally doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: This is not really clear... Your first snippet does not write anything so how could we know why it does not output what you want. Plus, how `array` was created ?

Comment: I just updated the code!
@dici

Comment: increasing the loop's counter `i` by `checkNextLine(array[i++])` is your intention? Depending on the content of `checkNextLine(int)`, one line might be just skipped.

Comment: You need to open the file in `r+` mode. The problem is that you are probably reading/writing from it through the try/finally bit. That's why your file pointer is moving to different location. rewind it if necessary.

Comment: @jp-jee checkNextLine() takes a String (content of array[i++]). Then it does a string comparison and returns a boolean depending if it is equal. But That shouldn't matter as I am printing the lines at the start of the loop.

Comment: @hagubear I'm only reading the file once and adding the line contents to an array. (in the order in which they are read) Then I'm using that array to get the each line. Unless i am misunderstanding you....

Comment: Seems to me like this checkNextLine(array[i++]) should be checkNextLine(array[i + 1])

Comment: @davidtenHove Well You have Fixed it! Can't believe that I missed that! Thank you! Mind making an answer and I'll mark it as best =)

Comment: uh... did you actually read my comment before replying to it, @user1767369 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change checkNextLine(array[i++]) to checkNextLine(array[i + 1]) or it will skip lines.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the counter i in the first sample without outputting the line:

```
   else if (isOverride(s)) {
        if (checkNextLine(array[i++])) {
            array[i] = "";
        }
    }
```